# Angular Material table dynamic columns

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have created mat-table component which generate dynamic columns by data which i pasted, but  without Action icons.

```
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="data" class="mat-elevation-z8">

      <ng-container [matColumnDef]="item.columnDef" *ngFor="let item of columns; let i = index">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ item.header }}</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element[item.columnDef] }}</td> 
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
    </table>
```

Data are pasted by **Input()** from another component.

```
    columns: Column [] = [
    {columnDef: 'faculty_id', header: 'ID'},
    {columnDef: 'faculty_name', header: 'Faculty'},
    {columnDef: 'faculty_description', header: 'Description'},
    {columnDef: 'action', header: 'Actions', actions: [
      {type: tableActionsType.Edit, icon: 'edit', matTooltip: 'Edit'},
      {type: tableActionsType.Delete, icon: 'delete', matTooltip: 'Delete'}
    ]}
  ];
```

- 

### What i need:

I want to generate  column **Actions** with icons,

-

### Problem:

I need to check in  this loop `*ngFor="let item of columns;`  when `item.columnDef === 'action'` and render *mat-icon*

```
    <ng-container [matColumnDef]="item.columnDef" *ngFor="let item of columns; let i = index">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ item.header }}</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">

      // if item.columnDef == 'action' then mat-icon
      // else  {{ element[item.columnDef] }}

       <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="edit" *ngFor="let icon of item.actions" [matTooltip]="icon.matTooltip" (click)="check()">{{icon.icon}}</mat-icon>
   
      </td>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: Any updates regarding this issue?

Comment: @Entertain Yes, I managed to solve it. Please check out the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I came up with this decision. And it works fine for me.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"  class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort>
  <ng-container [matColumnDef]="item.columnDef" *ngFor="let item of columns; let i = index">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header [disabled]="item.columnDef=='action'? true : false ">{{ item.header }}</th>
  
     <ng-container *ngIf="!item.actions"> // *if column is not the action column then render normal column
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">{{ item.header =='ID' ?  matPaginator.pageSize * matPaginator.pageIndex + i + 1 : element[item.columnDef] }}</td>
     </ng-container>
  
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="action-link">
       // *rendering actions in the action column for instance it can be edit or delete
       <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" [attr.aria-label]='action.aria_label' *ngFor="let action of item.actions"  [matTooltip]="action.matTooltip" (click)="getEvent(action,element)">{{action.icon}}</mat-icon>
     </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

One more solution

You can use **[ngSwitch]** to customize the column content per dynamic column

```html
  <table cdk-table [dataSource]="datasource | async">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let col of columnsToDisplay | async">
      <ng-container [ngSwitch]="col.id">

        **Action Column**
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'_action'" cdkColumnDef="_action">
          <th cdk-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>{{col.name}}</th>
          <td cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">
            <ng-container  *ngTemplateOutlet="#actionTemplate; context: {row: row}"> </ng-container>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        **All another column**
        <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault cdkColumnDef="{{col.id}}">
          <th cdk-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>{{col.name}}</th>
          <td cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">{{row[col.id]}}</td>
        </ng-container>

      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
    <tr cdk-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="columnsIDs | async"></tr>
    <tr cdk-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: (columnsIDs | async)"></tr>
  </table>
```

And template for action column

```html
<ng-template
  #actionTemplate
  let-row="row"
>
  <button
    [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
  </button>
  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <button></button>
    </mat-menu>
</ng-template>
```